# Xamarin Forms out of memory errors on orientation changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms. When I rotate the orientation, or sometimes when I just try to open a new page I get an unexpected error.

[See image here](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2j0b7m0/8)

> 0x21 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal
>
> 0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException
>
> 0x26 in object.7581e694-d3dd-45ce-9fdf-93ab5f3b26ee
>
> 0x11 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>
> 0x6A in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethode at /User/builder/data/lance/monodroid-milon-monodroid-4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1161,5
>
> 0x73 in Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap at /User/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-milon-monodroid-
>   4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.cs:621,21
>
> 0x7 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonDrawable.CreateBitmap
>
> 0x41 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonDrawable.Draw
>
> 0x13 in Android.Graphics/Drawables/Drawable.n_Draw_Landroid_graphics_Canvas_at /User/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-milon-monodroid-4.18-series/3b7ef0a7/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Graphics.Drawables/Drawable.cs:988,4
>
> 0x17 in object.7581e694-d3dd-45ce-9fdf-93ab5f3b26ee

This is the call stack with external code. 
When the android device logger is enabled it shows out of memory errors.
I have no idea to solve this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your work and error message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Added the error as text.

Comment: Need code to be certain but it looks pretty straight forward. You are loading a large bitmap or leaking an image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Backgroundimage or another Image inside your Pages?

I had the same issue.
I resolved it by loading/unloading backgroundimage from pages on navigation:

```
public override OnAppearing(...) { this.backgroundimage.Source = null; }
public override OnDisappearing(..) { this.backgroundimage.Source = your ImageSource; }
```

Big backgroundimages caused crashes in my android app. the ios version seemed to be handling it throwing no exception.